# How to use lstlisting package with regular expressions / special chars?

Tags: regex, latex, listings

I want to show a php function with a regex in a code snippet using the lstlisting package. TeX gives me several errors "*Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence*" and the dollar sign seems to put my tex code in math mode. The whole document is UTF-8 encoded. Any ideas how to correctly deal with these special chars in lstlisting environment? Thanks.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=php,label={lis:mylisting}]
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
  return preg_match("/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@()$%^&*=_{}[\]:;\"'|\\<>,.\/~`±§+-]).{8,255}$/", $value);
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the plus-minus and section symbol. You can add specify them as literate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=php,label={lis:mylisting},extendedchars=true,literate={±}{{$\pm$}}1 {§}{{\S}}1]
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
  return preg_match("/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@()$%^&*=_{}[\]:;\"'|\\<>,.\/~`±§+-]).{8,255}$/", $value);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, most of the errors are gone but there are still 2 left: 'Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence' and 'Invalid UTF-8 byte "9F'. Moreover the Dollar char still puts my tex code in math mode.

Comment: @Rome The code from my answer compiles without error. If you still experience errors, please make a `[mre]` that reproduces them

Comment: Okay, so something else in my code must be the issue. I'll get back to you if can't find them myself. Thanks again.